# Removing geos in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, postgis, geos

I installed `geos 3.6.2` following the tutorial here :

https://geonode.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/tutorials/admin/install/install_postgis.html

(except for the fact that I downloaded and installed `v3.6.2` and not `v3.3.8`)

Now I'd like to remove it. What is the clean way to do this ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jump into the folder you ran `make install` in and run `sudo make uninstall`. If that doesn't work, you'll have to run `./configure` first.

Comment: I added `make uninstall` to the official instructions at https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithAutotools